# Django url tag, variable as parameter

Tags: django, url

How do i pass a template variable to djangos url resolver as a parameter?

Something along these lines:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    {{ group.name }} 
    <a href="{% url 'group-view' group_code={{ group.group_code }} %}">MEMBER</a>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Documentation is pretty explicit about that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think you need variable tags inside another tag? You don't: as the documentation clearly shows, once you're inside a tag, you have direct access to the context variables.

```
{% url 'group-view' group_code=group.group_code %}
```

Comment: It seems quite simple now, but when your banging your head against the wall to get it working, you might miss it...